# Javascript array being set, no idea where

Tags: javascript, arrays

For a school project I need to make a game in C. However, since I'm much more fond with javascript + js can give a easy visual implementation, I decided to write my game in js before in c, to get my structure right. That's why my code's so weirdly looped.

Now, the issue is that I have a `switches[]` array that has the switches being pressed (1/0). I want to compare this to another array,  `oldArray[]`. Now, when comparing, they are both ALWAYS the same for some reason, and I just can't find it. Here's a full sample on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/yTttm/). The issue is in the `memory()` function. This line isn't working properly:

```
if (switches[i] == 1 && oldArray[i] == 0 && guessedArray[i] == 8 && i != oldtouch) {...}
```

because `switches[]` always seems to be equal to `oldArray[]`.

In the fiddle, press `Start` and check the consle output after clicking some buttons.

Comment: Where is `switches` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equal, because when the assignment statement `oldArray = switches` is executed, both variables point to the same underlying object in memory.

To copy all the values from one array to the other, without having them point to the same object, do `oldArray = switches.slice(0)`

See this for further discussion: [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Oh I see.. How do I only make the values equal then? So I only set all the values from `switches` to `oldArray` once, and when `switches` changes `oldArray` doesn't?

Comment: I edited the answer to add info on how to achieve your desired outcome.